# How to prioritize touches for my CCMenu?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have two CCMenu instances. At some point in the game, menu A is overlapped by menu B. However, when I press a button within menu B, the one that "gets it" is menu A.

How can I give touch priority to CCMenu B?

I tried this:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] setPriority:-130 forDelegate:menuB];
```

However, Xcode says that this delegate (menuB) was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I fixed this, but I still think there should be a better way.

First, we have to edit CCMenu's interface. We have to create a new integer property.

```
@interface CCMenu : CCLayer <CCRGBAProtocol>
{
    tCCMenuState state_;
    CCMenuItem  *selectedItem_;
    GLubyte     opacity_;
    ccColor3B   color_;

    int extraTouchPriority; // Our new integer
}

@property (readwrite) int extraTouchPriority;
```

Now change the `registerWithTouchDispatcher` method to this:

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:kCCMenuTouchPriority - extraTouchPriority swallowsTouches:YES];
}
```

Done. Now, when you have to give your CCMenu instance more priority than others, just give a higher `extraTouchPriority` value to it after initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What i did is copied the entire CCMenu from cocos2d library, renamed it  and then modified `kCCMenuTouchPriority` to what i wanted. Note that you have to rename `kCCMenuTouchPriority` for the custom menu. I used `kkCCMenuTouchPriority`.

I called it in code like this:

```
CCMenuPopUp *menu =[CCMenuPopUp menuWithItems:item1,nil];
```

I tried to subclass it but i ran into some problems and gave up and gone with the solution above.

the CCTouchDispatcher thing doesn't work because the menu isn't inited yet when you call it

Answer (score 0):

Here's anoter variation on one of the anwers above, which doesn't alter the cocos2D code base, because that is bad practice: https://gist.github.com/tudormunteanu/6174624